# Shunting-yard algorithm in Java, multiple digits in a number?

Tags: java, algorithm, shunting-yard

So I'm trying to implement the Shunting-yard algorithm in Java and I'm doing just fine doing so but my problem is that I want the string of text that gets evaluated by the algorithm to contain numbers with more than one digit.

I have a solution to this problem but the solution isn't that "beautiful". What I can do is that whenever a digit is found (within the main for-loop) I will concatenate it to a string and turn a Boolean variable to true to let the program know that we are within a number. When the for-loop finds a non-digit character the Boolean variable will turn false and we continue the algorithm as normal.

I don't find this solution to be very good since turning a Boolean variable true/false has been my to-go solution since forever whenever I'm stuck.

Any help please?

```
    while there are tokens to be read:
    read a token.
    **if the token is a number**, then push it to the output queue.
    if the token is an operator, then:
        while there is an operator at the top of the operator stack with
            greater than or equal to precedence:
                pop operators from the operator stack, onto the output queue;
        push the read operator onto the operator stack.
    if the token is a left bracket (i.e. "("), then:
        push it onto the operator stack.
    if the token is a right bracket (i.e. ")"), then:
        while the operator at the top of the operator stack is not a left bracket:
            pop operators from the operator stack onto the output queue.
        pop the left bracket from the stack.
        /* if the stack runs out without finding a left bracket, then there are
        mismatched parentheses. */
if there are no more tokens to read:
    while there are still operator tokens on the stack:
        /* if the operator token on the top of the stack is a bracket, then
        there are mismatched parentheses. */
        pop the operator onto the output queue.
exit.
```

I have highlighted the line where my problem occurs in the algorithm (3rd line). It says number, but the way I implement the algorithm I can only capture digits.

Thanks!

Comment: Paste your code? How are you reading the numbers?

Comment: I haven't written any code. Just pseudo code and I explained it^^

Comment: The pseudocode says "token", so it assumes you did tokenization.

Comment: Yes I might have missed that! Thank you, that kinda solved the problem!